# MySQL select re-ask+simplification

Tags: mysql

The original question is here.. [MySQL self-referencing ID and selects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6784604/856526)

I would like to pose the question in a way with all the relation to a specific case removed.

I have the example table..

```
id1     id2
1        5
5        1
2        3
3        2
```

What SQL command would return..

```
id1     id2
1       5
2       3
```

Essentially removing the "duplicate rows".

Comment: Those aren't quite duplicate rows...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1 and Q2 are the alias' I've created for your table, so we can reference the id's as if they were on different tables.

```
DELETE Q1 FROM table Q1 
     JOIN table Q2 
     ON Q1.id1 = Q2.id2 
     AND Q2.id1 = Q1.id2
     WHERE Q1.id1 > Q1.id2
```

Comment: Thanks, this gave me the idea on how to fix my problem!